# How to clear/remove all of the Weblogic logs without turning the server off?

Tags: java, logging, weblogic

Currently whenever I want to have only the most recent logs I have to delete all of the logs files and folders withint the logs folder of the domain. Unfortunately Weblogic has those files locked and I am only able to do that when Weblogic is off. Is there a way to clear/remove all of those logs without having to turn off Weblogic? It would be best if there would be a way to do that from the web/admin console.

Comment: All log files, or just all except the current log file? Also, which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a server to rotate its log and then remove the lock.
Use a wlst script to connect to the managed server and force log rotation :

```
connect('weblogic','...','t3://localhost:7001')
serverRuntime()
cd('LogRuntime/AdminServer')
cmo.forceLogRotation()
```